# ColdFusion: Common Update Pattern

Tags: coldfusion

I usually create update statements like this. But I know there is a better way. How can I approve upon this? *Note the sample below is pseudo demo, may not run.

```
<cffunction name="updateEmp" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="empId" required="yes" hint="empId">
    <cfargument name="firstName" required="yes" hint="firstName">
    <cfargument name="lastName" required="yes" hint="lastName">

    <!--- Get emp details in db --->
   <cfquery datasource="#ds#" name="getEmployee">
        SELECT *
        FROM Employee
        WHERE  emp_id = <cfqueryparam
                value="#arguments.empId#" 
                CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    </cfquery>

    <!--- If employee is in db or if emp db details are different --->
    <cfif getEmployee.recordCount eq 1 
            and getEmployee.firstName neq trim(arguments.firstName) 
             or getEmployee.lastName  neq trim(arguments.lastName)>

        <cfquery name="UpdateExistingEmployee" datasource="#ds#">

                UPDATE Employee
                SET 1 = 1
                    <cfif getEmployee.firstName neq trim(arguments.firstName)>
                        ,firstName = <cfqueryparam 
                                    value="#arguments.firstName#" 
                                    CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" >
                    </cfif>

                    <cfif getEmployee.lastName neq trim(arguments.lastName)>
                        ,lastName = <cfqueryparam 
                                    value="#arguments.lastName#" 
                                    CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" >
                    </cfif>

                WHERE emp_id=<cfqueryparam
                    value="#emp_id#" 
                    CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">

        </cfquery>

    </cfif>
    <!--- maybe return success? --->
</cffunction>
```

Edited:

```
<cffunction name="updateEmp" returntype="void">
        <cfargument name="empId" required="yes" hint="empId">
        <cfargument name="firstName" required="yes" hint="firstName">
        <cfargument name="lastName" required="yes" hint="lastName">

            <cfquery name="UpdateExistingEmployee" datasource="#ds#">

                    UPDATE Employee
                        SET firstName = <cfqueryparam 
                                        value="#arguments.firstName#" 
                                        CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" >

                            ,lastName = <cfqueryparam 
                                        value="#arguments.lastName#" 
                                        CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" >

                    WHERE emp_id=<cfqueryparam
                        value="#emp_id#" 
                        CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">

            </cfquery>

        <!--- maybe return success? --->
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: What problems with this are you seeing that you would like to improve on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to improve. If you just want to write less code you might just do an update:

```
<cffunction name="updateEmp" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="empId" required="yes" hint="empId">
    <cfargument name="firstName" required="yes" hint="firstName">
    <cfargument name="lastName" required="yes" hint="lastName">
    <cfquery name="UpdateExistingEmployee" datasource="#ds#">
      UPDATE Employee
      SET firstName = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.firstName#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
          ,lastName = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.lastName#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" >
      WHERE emp_id=<cfqueryparam value="#emp_id#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

The check for an existing record is pretty much superfluous since the where clause will prevent any action if no emp_id matches, and why bother checking if the names match? If they do, then you just updated them to be the same, if they don't you're going to update them anyway. There's no logical reason to be doing all that checking.

Comment: Plus, the table could change between the select and update statements.

Comment: Okay true. I had a weird idea that you shouldn't update values if the values from the submitted form are the exact same. And also, do you return any values from the update statement such as updated id?

Comment: Well I think if you have a way of knowing without making a call to the db (like already having your Employee table in memory), then yes, avoid it. There isn't much overhead to running a query, but there is always some, so my opinion is that it's best to reduce the number of queries as much as possible. You can return the update ID if you want, but you fed the id as an argument, so you already know it, not much reason to. You might put a try/catch in and just return a Boolean if the query ran successfully or not. But as it is, a failure will trigger a CF error that will give you that info.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check out Coldfusion ORM? Or, for something that would require less drastic changes to your codebase, you could use DataMgr (which really helps cut down on CRUD): http://datamgr.riaforge.org/